# System.Text.Json custom serializer for CosmosDb serialises all fields... except id

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, system.text.json, c#-10.0

**.Net 6, C#10**

This is my classes hierarchy:

```
public interface IWithKey {
   public Guid Id {get; }
}

public interface IType : IWithKey {
   public string Payload { get; }
   // a bunch of other complex fields (strings, Guids, nested objects...)
}

public class MyBaseType : IWithKey {

   [JsonInclude]
   public Guid Id {get; protected set; }


   public MyBaseType(Guid id) {
       Id = id;
   }
}

public class MyType : MyBaseType, IType {
   public Guid Id { get; private set; }
   public string Payload { get; private set; }
   // a bunch of other complex fields (strings, Guids, nested objects...)

   public MyType(Guid id, string payload, /* all the other fields... */)
   : base(id)
  {
        Payload = payload;
        // all the other fields...
   }
}
```

I have a custom Cosmos serializer. It exists solely to let me use system.Text.Json instead of Newtonsoft's Json.Net (as explained here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/issues/202 )

```
   using System.Text.Json;
   using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos;


   public class CosmosNetSerializer : CosmosSerializer
   {
      private readonly JsonSerializerOptions? _serializerOptions;

      public CosmosNetSerializer() => _serializerOptions = null;

      public CosmosNetSerializer(JsonSerializerOptions serializerOptions) =>
         this._serializerOptions = serializerOptions;

      public override T FromStream<T>(Stream stream)
      {
         using (stream)
         {
            if (typeof(Stream).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
            {
               return (T)(object)stream;
            }

            return JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<T>(stream, _serializerOptions).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
         }
      }

      public override Stream ToStream<T>(T input)
      {
         var outputStream = new MemoryStream();
       

         // A BREAKPOINT HERE SHOWS THAT 'input' has all the fields, including Id

         JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync<T>(outputStream, input, _serializerOptions).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

         // A BREAKPOINT HERE AND A LOOK INSIDE 'outputStream' shows that ALL the fields have been serialized EXCEPT 'Id' or 'id.

         outputStream.Position = 0;
         return outputStream;
      }
   }
}
```

Not that it matters, but the serializer is instantiated this way :

```
     var options = new(JsonSerializerDefaults.Web);
     var cosmosOptions = new CosmosClientOptions
     {
        ConnectionMode = //...,
        Serializer = new CosmosNetSerializer(options)
     };

     var cosmosClient = CosmosClient
           .CreateAndInitializeAsync(connectionString, containersList, cosmosOptions);
```

The serialization is triggered by inserting into Cosmos :

```
     var container = cosmosClient.GetContainer("myDatabase", "myContainer");

     var item = GetItem();
     await container.CreateItemAsync(item, "partitionKey", null);
```

Please note the subtlety : It lies in how the item is obtained. It's not of type `MyType` but of type `IType` :

```
public IType GetItem() {
    return new MyType(id : Guid.NewGuid(), payload: "YYYY", /* all the other fields... */)
}
```

**Problem:**

**Look again at the comments in the serializer's code.**
`input` is a full-blown object of type `IType` (*passed* as `IType` but the breakpoint shows that C# understands that, in effect, it's a `MyType`).
It **does** have a field "Id" with a valid value, and a **TON** of other custom fields. Some of them with custom converters, some with nested objects, etc.

Absolutely **everything** gets serialized, I can see it in `outputStream`...
...Except for '`Id`' or '`id`', which goes missing.

Why?

Comment: Just a guess, but what happens if you include the decorator [JsonInclude] above public Guid Id in MyType?  From: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to?pivots=dotnet-7-0#include-fields

Comment: Cosmos DB requires the `id` field to be lowercase and a String, your property is `Id`. You can try decorating it with `[JsonPropertyName("id")]` to make sure the name when serializing is correct?

Comment: @bdcoder it didn't help... However I edited my answer to add the existence of class `MyBaseType` ... Maybe the fishy business comes from inheritance... I strongly suspect it.

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta it just so happens that I do have `[JsonPropertyName("id")]` in the schema, I just forgot to include it here. I will edit the question. Please note, however, that setting `JsonSerializerDefaults.Web` is supposed to protect me from that. Also the field goes missing BEFORE Cosmos even gets to see the data.

Comment: the issue was caused by "Id" being the only field coming from an underlying class. As it has been explained numerous times in StackOverflow, in .Net6 the serializer doesn't know how to handle the fields of ancestor classes. changing `SerializeAsync<T>`  to `SerializeAsync<object>`  fixed the issue...

Answer (score 1):

The issue was caused by the class hierarchy. `Id` was the only field coming from an underlying class, and System.Text.Json requires extra wotk to handle serialization of class hierarchies.

I changed this :
`SerializeAsync<T>`

to this :
`SerializeAsync<object>`

...as suggested in some posts that explain how to handle class hierarchies in **.Net6** with System.Text.Json.

If I had been using **.Net7** then there exist "better" solutions where you indicate the class hierarchy with decorators above each class definition.